# Program taking too much time

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, memory-efficient

I'm trying to solve a coding problem, the problem is:

- Take a string input
- Take a number input 'n'
- Repeat the string up to n indexes
- Count the number of 'a' characters that occur in the repeated string

**This problem was authored by tunyash on Hackerrank with title 'Repeated String'**

**My current solution is taking too much time to run**

This is what I am currently doing:

1. Use a variable to iterate through the original string
2. Each time the variable exceeds the original string length, reset it to 0
3. Iterate n times

I've made a function to do the counting as follows:

```
long long repeatedString(std::string s, long long n) {
    long long sIndex{ 0 }, length = s.size(), result{ 0 };
    

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if (sIndex > (length - 1))
            sIndex = 0;

        if (s[sIndex] == 'a')
            result += 1;

        sIndex += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've tried modifying and using binary search algorithm by first writing the whole string then searching but the writing part takes too much time and seems not very intuitive

Comment: Don't need to search the string repeatedly. Just do the search once in the substring and then use maths to calculate the final count for the full string.

Comment: @kaylum thank u for the tip, I can work it out from that

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical beginner programming exercise. The idea is that you shouldn't blindly overengineer the problem, when a simple mathematical formula is right around the corner. In this case you can simply count the number of `a`'s in the original string and multiply it by `n` to get the desired result:

```
std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a') * n
```

where `s` is your input string.

Edit: I misinterpreted the question. I assumed `n` was the number of repetitions of the whole string, whereas it actually was the number of characters to concatenate by modularly concatenating the strings characters up until `n` number of characters. In this case, simply divide before multiplying: `n / s.length()` and adjust for the `n % s.length()` characters remaining with addition. I will leave this as an exercise.

Comment: `n` is not guaranteed to be a whole multiple of the substring length.

Comment: I think I can work it out from this, thank u for the help

Comment: I have edited the answer to clear up my misconception.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO yes this is the thing that worked 
```result = ((n / s.size()) + (n - ((n / s.size()) * length))) * nOfA
``` but I got the idea of what to do anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: Sweet! Good luck!